# having trouble to align mysql data in the in pdf

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

i want to align my data properly in pdf file frm mysql database. but the result i get is not wat i want,  some last column just come below the other while i wanted to align with the other column.
i have tried something like this.

```
while (ob_get_level())
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Encoding: None", true);




$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db_name="pdf_test";
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("cannot connect to the  
database".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn)or die("cannot select the database".mysql_error());


include('fpdf.php');

$q=mysql_query("select * from education_mailstone");
$number_of_persons=mysql_num_rows($q);

//initialize the 4 columns and the total
$column_name="";
$column_school="";
$column_year="";
$column_score="";

//For each row add field to the specific column
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$name=$row['name'];
$school=$row['school'];
$year=$row['year'];
$score=$row['score'];


$column_name=$column_name.$name."\n";
$column_school=$column_school.$school."\n";
$column_year=$column_year.$year."\n";
$column_score=$column_score.$score."\n";
}



$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$Y_Fields_Name_position=20;
$Y_Table_position=26;
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(400,6,'NAME OF STUDENT',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(60);
$pdf->Cell(400,6,'NAME OF THE SCHOOL',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(120);
$pdf->Cell(400,6,'COMPLETION YEAR',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(180);
$pdf->Cell(50,6,'SCORE',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_position);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->MultiCell(400,6,$column_name,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_position);
$pdf->SetX(60);
$pdf->MultiCell(400,6,$column_school,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_position);
$pdf->SetX(120);
$pdf->MultiCell(400,6,$column_year,1);
$pdf->SetX(180);
$pdf->MultiCell(50,6,$column_score,1);
$pdf->Ln();
$i = 0;
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_position);
while ($i < $number_of_persons)
{
    $pdf->SetX(10);
    $pdf->MultiCell(120,6,'',1);
    $i = $i +1;
}
$pdf->Output();
```

**so wat am i doin wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve a table with the headings going across horizontally and the names and details going across in columns below?

If so I'm not sure why you are setting each of your cells to the width of 400mm
$pdf->Cell(400,6,'NAME OF STUDENT',1,0,'L',1);

It looks like you are trying to make your cells 60mm wide with your SetX function? Is there any reason why you are doing this instead of having your code as 
$pdf->Cell(60,6,'NAME OF STUDENT',1,0,'L',1); This way you shouldn't need to setX each time afterwards and the next Cell 'NAME OF SCHOOL' should automatically line up to the right of this one?

Then for your MultiCell's you should really have the width of this as 60 also 
$pdf->MultiCell(60,6,$column_school,1);

If this doesn't help at all could you perhaps upload a link of what it's currently displaying for you.

For some basic information on using FPDF I have recently written a blog on the basics of FPDF, as the website isn't too helpful with it's instructions

http://www.limelightonline.co.nz/blog/create-dynamic-pdf-with-php-tutorial/

Not sure this might help you out?

Thanks,
Shay.